# Angular - 400 error when using a generic base service with different id property name

Tags: angular, typescript, crud

I am using a base class service with **id** property name when selecting a given item, but I have other components that use different property names.

For a custom component that uses 'code' instead of 'id', when I click to update an item (PUT method), the console gives me a 400 error, and shows a bad Request URL:

http://example.com/api/items/**code**

instead of

http://example.com/api/items/**C002**

The payload shown is correct: > { code:"C002", name "Item 2" }

The item class is as follows:

```
export interface Item {
    code: string;
    name: string;
    }
```

The component method:

```
updateItem(form: FormGroup) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      form.value.id = params['code'];

      this.itemService.update('code', form.value)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.router.navigate(['/list']);
        });
    });
}
```

and the base class service:

```
public update(id: string, dto: INDTO): Observable<OUTDTO> {
    return this.http.put<OUTDTO>(`/${this.controllerName}/${id}`, dto, this.endPointFactory.getRequestHeaders());
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You pass 'code' as first parameter of you update function. And the first parameter is called id. So you have 'code' in id. Replace 'code' by form.value.id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is slightly issue in the calling the service function. Instead of passing hard coded value `code`, eight your should pass the `form.value.id` or `params['code']`.

> Modified code is as

```
updateItem(form: FormGroup) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      form.value.id = params['code'];
      this.itemService.update(form.value.id, form.value)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.router.navigate(['/list']);
        });
    });
}
```